# How can I handle arguments

Tags: vbscript

I have found a script which suits my needs. However, I'd like to enhance it.

This is the script:

```
strSSH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe"
strSSHidentity1 = "C:\id_rsa.ppk"
strSSHidentity2 = "C:\id_dsa.ppk"

Select Case WScript.Arguments.Count
    Case 0
        WScript.Echo "No hostname provided.  Aborting SSH operation."
        WScript.Quit
    Case Else
        Set colArgs = WScript.Arguments
        For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count - 1
            strHost = " " & WScript.Arguments.Item(i)
        Next
End Select

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """" & strSSH & """ """ & CleanHostname(strHost) & """ """ & "-i" & """ """ & strSSHidentity1 & """ """ & "-i" & """ """ & strSSHidentity1 & """"
WScript.Quit

Function CleanHostname(strHost)
    strHost = Trim(strHost)
    'Remove protocol if it was passed
    If InStr(strHost, "ssh://") = 1 Then
        strHost = Right(strHost, Len(strHost) - 6)
    End If
    'Remove trailing slash if present
    If InStrRev(strHost, "/") = Len(strHost) Then
        strHost = Left(strHost, Len(strHost) - 1)
    End If
    'Return cleaned hostname
    CleanHostname = strHost
End Function
```

I use it to enable the ssh:// hyperlink.
How can modify it so it'll accept more arguments provided by the user in the commandline than just the hostname? (`-p 22`) for example.

Examples for requested output:

CMD:

```
wscript ssh.vbs ssh://root@myhost -p 22 -i my_key.ppk
```

Would eventually run:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" myhost -i C:\id_rsa.ppk -i C:\id_dsa.ppk -p 22 -i my_key.ppk
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you use .Arguments (i.e. .Arguments.Unnamed) to get a list of hosts, further
parameters should be passed via .Arguments.Named. In code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goWAN : Set goWAN = WScript.Arguments.Named
Dim goWAU : Set goWAU = WScript.Arguments.UnNamed

Dim sPort : sPort = "22"

If 0 = goWAU.Count Then
   WScript.Echo "need at least one hostname"
Else
   Dim u
   For Each u in goWAU
       WScript.Echo "Host:", u
   Next
   If goWAN.Exists("p") Then sPort = goWAN("p")
   WScript.Echo "Port:", sPort
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 29256477.vbs
need at least one hostname

cscript 29256477.vbs pi pa po
Host: pi
Host: pa
Host: po
Port: 22

cscript 29256477.vbs pi /p:23
Host: pi
Port: 23

cscript 29256477.vbs pi /p:4711 pa po
Host: pi
Host: pa
Host: po
Port: 4711
```